# Move to a cell in excel after a sort of data

Tags: excel

I have a few macros running the sorts data. My issue is after the macro runs the range of data stays selected. I want to be able to move and activate cell A1. I have attached the code below and any help would be much appreciated. Ps Can I also save the file in the macro.

```
Sub JBHM()
'
' JBHM Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
Range("E6:E44").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("C6:G44").Select
Range("G6").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boys Junior 100M").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boys Junior 100M").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "E6:E44"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boys Junior 100M").Sort
    .SetRange Range("C6:G44")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The below will do as you ask. The range function with the select will cause the selection to change to the specified location. ActiveWorkbook.Save saves the current workbook the same as if you pressed ctrl S or hit the save button.

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```